# How can a phone transmit the signal back to tower?

Tags: rf, antenna, transmitter, cellphone, telecommunications

If cellphones have such a low power transmitter (around 200mW for LTE) and also doesn't have directionality then how can they talk back to the tower even though they are so powerful and built specifically with aim for better direction.
And how sensitive are the tower receivers?

Comment: They are not “so powerful”. Average power is 10W in a tower

Comment: But relatively powerful than typical cell phone. Although please answer my question.

Comment: Also, I believe cell phones are not only 200mW, they can reach much higher power bursts with 2A peaks

Comment: LTE have Tx 200mW. And what voltage you said it peaks at 2AMPS?

Comment: The AVERAGE power of a cellphone transmitter is as you say in the 2-300mW range.  
However the PEAK power is much higher. Depending on the cellphone model it's in the 2-6W range. The power is adaptive, low when close to a tower and higher when far away.

Comment: 6 W? That would really eat away the puny batteries in phone's.

Comment: I don't see experts on SE giving answers.

Comment: @ObsessionWithElectricity Do not confuse power with energy. Small batteries provide low energy capacity but high power can be easily achieved.

Comment: That is why it only transmit 6 W when it absolutely has to, to reach the tower.

Comment: Won't using high power drain the battery faster.

Comment: Think about communicating with a space probe (like Voyager). The ground station can transmit a very strong signal, but the remote probe only has limited power available and transmits back a very weak signal. We use very large antennas, careful receiver designs, maybe even cryogenic electronics, to receive those signals. But yet we can receive them. The cell phone situation is similar but without so much distance or so much disparity between the base and remote transmitter power.

Comment: Yes, using high power drains the battery faster. That is why you only do it when the alternative is no connection at all or a dropped call.

Comment: Can you tell me the sensitivity of the receiving antenna on the cell tower?

Comment: It isn't just the antenna.  It also depends on the receiver circuitry, and the processing that goes on after the signal is received.

Comment: But isn't there a physical limitation due to thermal noise or something?

Comment: Surprisingly I found an excellent presentation on the subject of antennas which answers a lot of the detailed questions: http://www.artisan-itn.net/documents/Hesselbarth_lecture.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I'm out of date on how modern mobile telephone networks handle multiple simultaneous voice calls but I believe each phone is allocated a time slot and there may be up to 100 time slots but it could be forty (something nagging in the back of my mind!).

However it doesn't matter for answering this question; we can assume 100 time slots and that means the phone has to compress its outgoing voice message and transmit it in one hundredth of the time that the old fashioned analogue system had. That old system allocated a frequency for each handset and is now out-of-date.

Let's assume that the voice data could be compressed to 10 kbps and given that it has to be transmitted in one-hundredth the time it will need to store  data and transmit it at about 1 Mbps. Again, don't hang me on this if I'm not up to the latest 4G methods because that isn't important for this question I feel.

So, the tower receiver is handling a data rate of around 1 Mbps continuously to service up to 100 simultaneous voice calls. How much received power does the tower antenna need to adequately recover the data you would consider next.

The thermal noise per hertz for 50 ohms is -174 dBm and we wish to exceed this with sufficient margin to make data reception viable so, a well trodden formula says we need 100 times this power or -154 dBm. But that is "per Hz" and we need to have a bandwidth of about 1 MHz to adequately convert an RF signal carrying 1 Mbps data back to usable data. So the formula (at an ambient of 25 degC) becomes: -

Received power in dBm = -154 dBm + 10 log\$_{10}\$(data rate)

For the example of 1 MHz BW, we need a received signal in the order of -94 dBm. Given that RF engineers normally load this with a thing called fade margin (20 dB to 30 dB more) we would probably be OK statistically with -74 dBm.

Then there is link loss and the formula for free space is this:-

Link loss (dBm) = 32.45 + 20 loglog\$_{10}\$(Fc) + 20 log log\$_{10}\$(distance in km)

Fc is in MHz and is the carrier frequency. I'm going to assume that the telephone carrier frequency is about 2 GHz but don't hang me if I'm too far out.

If the distance is 3 km then the link loss is 32.45 dB + 66 dB +9.54 dBm. Overall that is about 108 dB lost between transmitter and receiver but we will have antenna gain and this could drop to maybe 102 dB or better.

We need -74 dBm therefore we need to transmit a level that is 102 dB higher or 28 dBm. 28 dBm is a power of 631 mW. Not a million miles from the 200 mW but the important thing is that you know have the fundamentals to put the real numbers into.

Comment: How did you calculated link loss?

Comment: @ObsessionWithElectricity it's the standard Friis transmission link loss equation expressed in decibel form. Try [this calculator](https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-friis.aspx) to save you a little time.

Comment: There's also [this one](https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-fspl.aspx) that directly gives link loss.

Comment: BTW so the frequency does matter in terms of range of signal?. I read someone posted on SE that frequency doesn't matter. I always doubted him.

Comment: And wouldnt the gain of cell phone antenna which transmit the signal affect the power received by the BTS?

Comment: What is the gain of cellphone antennas generally?

Comment: Frequency does matter. A quarter wave monopole antenna at 2 GHz is ten times smaller than a QWMA at 200 MHz therefore it cannot have the "collection" area that the bigger one has. Not sure of the cellphone antenna gain. I can't see it being more than 3 dBi.

Comment: Friis allows for the ever smaller antennas (for a given gain) with rising frequency by considering the path loss to rise with frequency, this is equivalent to saying that at higher frequency the antenna captures power from a smaller area of the sphere around the transmitter. Now if you have a given amount of space you can maybe accommodate a higher gain antenna in that space at a higher frequency and thereby cancel out the frequency term in Friis, but that is expressed in the antenna gain term.

Comment: Frequency does not matter for power density (to a first order), power in W/square meter (or mW/cm^2, or whatever) is independent of frequency (at least below the high microwave bands), but aerials get smaller for a given gain as frequency rises, so the capture area as a fraction of the area of the sphere falls with rising frequency (Antenna design being otherwise unchanged).

Comment: @DanMills exactly!

Comment: One more thing: If the cell tower has high enough gain to receive a very faint signal from the cellphone why do they then use such high power transmitters (I heard it's 40W for LTE) to transmit to the phone? Doesn't higher gain help with connection both ways?

Comment: Using a higher power mast transmitter means you can use cheaper (and less power hungry) receivers in the phone. Cost and performance benefit!

Comment: Wait a minute. Doesn't high gain antenna, (on it's own)  installed at cell tower allow it to transmit low power signals to the phone? And why would a receiver need power? An FM receiver doesn't need it.

Comment: Why dont they just use the 200mW transmitter like that on the phones? Is it because they are omnidirectional, but so are cell phones.

Comment: You can't use a high gain antenna because it's too directional. Receivers need power to amplify signals. An FM receiver in a transistor radio certainly needs receiver power. Read my prev comment regards your last comment.

Comment: So are you saying that cell phone towers have good gain on receiving antenna for better reception but low gain on transmitting antenna for higher coverage of area (being omnidirectional)?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83266/discussion-between-obsessionwithelectricity-and-andy-aka).

Comment: I'm not saying anything about antenna gain other than it might be between 0 dBi and 3 dBi at either end in order to not make anything too directional. I'm saying lowish gain.

Comment: At one point you said that the tower has very high gain hence it can receive faint signal but then you said that it doesn't have very  high gain because it need not directivity. I meant to ask that do the tower have high gain receiver but low gain transmitters?

Comment: No I didn't; as far as I'm aware I've only suggested low gain (0 dBi to 3 dBi). I also have never mentioned "faint signals". Virtually all radios have high gain receivers (note that I said receivers and not receiving antennas). The concept of a low gain transmitter doesn't make sense. The concept of a low gain transmit antenna does.

Comment: You want to say Antennas have gain their transmitters or receivers don't. But I get it. Only thing I am asking is if two different antennas of different gains are used for transmission and reception on cell sites?

Comment: I don’t know that detail. I cannot say whether some towers use a common transmit/receive antenna or two separate ones.